# How to open a webview over current layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-webview

Been searching for this for a while. How do I open a webview that will appear on top of my current layout ? The webview will show a webpage from the internet where users enter their details and submit it.

If anyone has played with Facebook login, Twitter login, or even PayPal payment, they are all doing exactly what I want, a webview floating on top of the current layout please see the screenshot below:

**please note,** I will not create my own webview textboxes and buttons, it will be a webpage from a url that I wish to display in that webview

[image: application with no webview]

[image: application with facebook login webview]

[image: application with twitter login webview]

[image: application with paypal payment webview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just launch it in a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Dialogs can be themed with custom layouts to look like pretty much anything.

If you still need more flexibility, try using a dialog themed Activity.

Comment: thanks a lot for editing the question to look better and for your answer, but can you clarify more please, can I have a webview within a dialog ?

Comment: @Heiba Yeah. You can add any arbitrary layout to the dialog. The page I linked you to shows how.